# How to open a fix excel file in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the below code where I am using , I am looking for a way where I can fix the filename with the proper path.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-excelsheet',
  templateUrl: './excelsheet.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./excelsheet.component.css']
})
export class ExcelsheetComponent implements OnInit {

  data: [][];
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onFileChange(evt: any) {
    const target: DataTransfer = < DataTransfer > (evt.target);

    //const target : File ='Demo.XLSX'; 

    if (target.files.length !== 1) throw new Error('Cammot use multiple files');

    const reader: FileReader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      const bstr: string = e.target.result;
      const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.read(bstr, {
        type: 'binary'
      })
      const wsname: string = wb.SheetNames[0];
      const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = wb.Sheets[wsname];
      console.log(ws);
      this.data = (XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {
        header: 1
      }));
      console.log(this.data);
    }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

I am using a drag a drop feature whereas I want to open a fix excel file, any idea how may I do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
1   

addfile(event)     
    2     {    
    3     this.file= event.target.files[0];     
    4     let fileReader = new FileReader();    
    5     fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file);     
    6     fileReader.onload = (e) => {    
    7         this.arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;    
    8         var data = new Uint8Array(this.arrayBuffer);    
    9         var arr = new Array();    
    10        for(var i = 0; i != data.length; ++i) arr[i] = String.fromCharCode(data[i]);    
    11        var bstr = arr.join("");    
    12        var workbook = XLSX.read(bstr, {type:"binary"});    
    13        var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];    
    14        var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];    
    15        console.log(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true}));    
    16          var arraylist = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet,{raw:true});     
    17              this.filelist = [];    
    18              console.log(this.filelist)    
    19      
    20    }    
    21  }    

<input type="file" class="form-control" (change)="addfile($event)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".csv,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, application/vnd.ms-excel">
```

Comment: I want to fix the file name from my local system, Please tell me from where I can fix the filename with path. like this:
file="C:\abc.xlsx"